# Global Reference of Square payment form object into Angular

Tags: typescript, square

There's no implementation of a [Square](https://squareup.com/ca/payments) checkout form for Angular 4/5/6 so I'm trying to figure out what this might entail by creating a test component, but I can't figure out how to get a reference to their global object [SqPaymentForm](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/sqpaymentform/sqpaymentform-overview) into Angular and have TypeScript not throw an error saying it doesn't exist on the window object as `window.SqPaymentForm` since it does exist.

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to have TypeScript recognize that `window.SqPaymentForm` exists?

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    { provide: 'SQUARE', useFactory: getSquare }
  ]
})
export class SquareModule { }

export function getSquare() {
  return (typeof window !== undefined) 
      // TypeScript indicates it doesn't exist on Window 
      ? window.SqPaymentForm 
      : null;
}
```

Comment: This seem like a timing thing, can you hold off on calling the payment form until it is initialized?

Comment: It should be loaded.  The script loads in the <head> of index.html, but trying to now load the reference as a provider.  I was hoping I could use it as a provider and when the checkout component loads that I could invoke something similar to their example, but can't get it to build to test that theory due to `window.SqPaymentForm` not existing according to TypeScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out I had to create my own typings, but couldn't figure out how to load it via a `.d.ts` so, for now, it is declared in the Square module:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    SqPaymentForm: any;
  }
}
```

or replace `window.SqPaymentForm` with:

```
(<any>window).SqPaymentForm
```

Comment: Thanks for following up with your answer for the benefit of other developers!

Comment: No problem @tristansokol, I really like Square and would like to use them for everything. Right now their POS works great for our client, but I'm having some issues integrating this into an Angular SPA based on how the forms are loaded using iframes and how they are configured, which is really easy to do using Stripe (and even Paypal) by comparison.

Comment: Are you using `autoBuild:false`? that can help control page timings quite a bit.

Comment: Isn't this a Typescript issue rather than Angular specific? It's just the case than in Typescript, there is no "SqPaymentForm" property on the Window type.